# Unexpected T_ENDWHILE in loop.php

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I'm doing a new theme from scratch (the previous one hasn't been updated for several years) and I wanted to try it.
Everything seemed to go well except when I want to list posts, I get this error :

**Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ENDWHILE in /wp-content/themes/pro/loop.php on line 41**

Here is the cleaned up code :

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
  <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a><small>, le <?php the_date(); ?></small></h2>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">
        <?php
            if ( $post->post_excerpt ){
                the_excerpt();?>
                <div class="btn-group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lire la suite <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw"></i></a></button>
                </div>
            <?php }
            else {
                the_content();?>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-footer">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments"><i class="fa fa-comments fa-fw"></i> <?php get_comments_number(); ?></a></button>
        </div>
         
        <i class="fa fa-folder-open fa-fw"></i> Catégories : <?php the_category(', ') ?>
    </div>
    </div>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="jumbotron">
    <h1>Il n'y a rien à afficher.</h1>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And I use this as index/archive/tags.php :

```
<?php
get_header();
get_template_part('loop');
get_footer();
?>
```

I looked up at my previous themes and it looks fine to me. What could cause this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `else` branch of the inner `if` (that one right before the `endwhile`) is missing its `}` somewhere before the `endwhile` keyword.

I guess the code should look like this:

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <?php
        if ( $post->post_excerpt ){
            the_excerpt();?>
            <div class="btn-group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Lire la suite <i class="fa fa-arrow-right fa-fw"></i></a></button>
            </div>
        <?php }
        else {
            the_content();
        } /* <- This bracket is missing */ ?>
</div>
```

Comment: And... You were right, the missing bracket caused the error. I can't believe I omitted it, even after I checked multiple time.